# Cropping an image on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, crop

I'm building a simple image editor on Qt.I have opened my image on a QGraphicsView and i want to be able to crop it.After a lot of search i came up with this code but it doesn't work.

```
void MainWindow::on_openButton_pressed()
{
    QString imagePath=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open File"),"",tr("JPEG (*.jpg *.jpeg);;PNG (*.png)"));
    imageObject=new QImage();
    imageObject->load(imagePath);
    image=QPixmap::fromImage(*imageObject);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    scene->addPixmap(image);
    scene->setSceneRect(image.rect());
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    ui->graphicsView->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag);
    showEvent();
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    start=event->pos();
}

void MainWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    end=event->pos();
}

void MainWindow::on_cropButton_clicked()
{
    start=ui->graphicsView->mapFromScene(start);
    end=ui->graphicsView->mapFromScene(end);
    QRect rect(start, end);
    cropped.size()=rect.size();
    cropped=image.copy(rect);
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addPixmap(cropped);
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->setSceneRect(cropped.rect());
    showEvent();
}
```

Can anybody find where is the mistake or propose a better way to do it?
Thank you a lot.

Comment: Did you try debugging? What is the value of `rect`? Is it what you expect it to be? What exactly happens in your application?

Comment: you are right the value of rect isn't the expected can you think of another way to fix this rather than the press and release event?

Comment: Why are you listening for the mouse events in the `MainWindow` class when it seems like you should be listening for the events in the `QGraphicsScene`? That way you probably won't have to worry about translating the coordinates. Also, you should note that you are not removing the old pixmap from the scene. Maybe you should keep a pointer to the existing `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and set a new pixmap to it. `QGraphicsScene::addPixmap` returns a `QGraphicsPixmapItem`.